# wrong number of indices inside []; expected 2

Tags: c#

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int width;
    int height;

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the width of the array");
    width = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the height of the array");
    height = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    int[,] grid = new int [width,height];

    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(grid[x][y]);
        }
    }
```

Just to be clear i am a beginner, and all the other answers are either way too complex or i just straight up cant understand them. the line in which i am getting the error is this:

```
int[,] grid = new int[width, height];
```

Comment: Are you sure about the line? the line you indicated is fine. You do have a problem in `Console.WriteLine(grid[x][y]);`. It should be `grid[x, y]`

Comment: Thanks it works now

Comment: And if you are searching for an explanation of arrays, you can find pretty much about them in the documentation of the [Array Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 7):

You're mixing up [multidimensional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays) arrays and [jagged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) arrays. Multidimensional arrays are always rectangular<sup>1</sup>, and are indexed by multiple indices inside a single indexer:

```
grid[x,y]
```

Jagged arrays are arrays of arrays, and are not necessarily rectangular. You access an element by indexing into the outer array with one indexer, and then using a second indexer to access the element:

```
grid[x][y]
```

In your case, you've created a multidimensional array - you need to use the first syntax.

<sup>1</sup>Or whatever the appropriate term is with a higher number of dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Console.WriteLine(grid[x, y]);` instead of `Console.WriteLine(grid[x][y]);`

Answer (score 0):

> ### Working Code

Console.WriteLine(grid[x, y]);.

Comment: You should accept the answer which explains you where the problem was, and eventually update your Question code with the solution, instead of making a new answer with the working code.